# How to define 00-90 when I have charAt each of it

Tags: java

What I need to do is write a program that makes the first character (which is charAt(0) )and the second character (which is charAt(1) ) to become a value that not exceeding 90 which is (0 ~ 90) , but I also have to define them as an independent digit , because my program will make it to invalid if it is other than a digit.

So for an example it will become invalid if I type in 91
and it will valid if I type in number between 0~90

but I have no idea how to do this...

```
  if(Character.isDigit(loop1.charAt(0))&&  
     Character.isDigit(loop1.charAt(1)))
```

I have tried this ,but not working

```
  if(Character.isDigit(loop1.charAt(0)) &&  
     Character.isDigit(loop1.charAt(1)) && 
      ((loop1 >= 0)&&(loop1 <= 90)))
```

also this one but this is not working( I have no idea what I'm doing)

```
   if(Character.isDigit(loop1.charAt(0)) &&  
      (((int)loop1.charAt(0)) >= 0) && <=9
      Character.isDigit(loop1.charAt(1)) && 
      ((int)loop1.charAt(1)) <= 9)
```

Please help me... thanks a million !

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you rephrase?

Comment: Casting a char to int does not convert it to the expected digit.  '1' does not equal 1.  You can compare char values directly: for example:  x.charAt(0) <= '9'

Comment: I have edited my question...Sorry Im not very good at explaining things....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am getting this right you want to convert the first two characters of a string into a number and check is that number bigger than 90. Also you want the digits to be stored in different variables(?). If so this code should do it:

```
int digit1 = loop1.charAt(0) - '0';
int digit2 = loop1.charAt(1) - '0';
int number = digit1 * 10 + digit2;
if ( number <= 90 && number >= 0 )
    System.out.println("Input is good");
else
    System.out.println("Input is bad");
```

Comment: Hi , your answer is helping me!!! But I don't understand this                                               loop1.charAt(0) - '0'    what is the meaning of -'

Comment: @ShangHuang A character in java can be represented as an integer as well(it's ascii value). So what `loop1.charAt(0) - '0'` does is take the ascii value of the first character and subtract the ascii value of the character '0' from it therefore leaving you with the digit itself.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand your question, parse `loop1` and test the values using a simple `if` check, like

```
int t = Integer.parseInt(loop1);
if (t < 0 || t > 90) {
    System.out.println("Value outside accepted range.");
} else {
    System.out.println("Value valid."); 
}
```